# HotTowel Durandal Inject different views based on the user

Tags: javascript, durandal, hottowel

In the `shell.html` for HotTowel template we have:

```
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!--/ko-->
```

which will automatically insert the proper view by convention. I am trying to inject different views based on the user's role in a HotTowel/Durandal App. For example,
I have two Views,

1. productEditor_Admin.html
2. productEditor_Superviser.html
   (instead of these two views, I used to have only productEditor.html, by convention everything worked)

and only a single ViewModel:

1. productEditor.js

Now, I want to have a function in `productEditor.js` that will let me decide which view to insert based on user's role. I see in the [Composition documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/), we can do `function strategy(settings) : promise` but I am not sure what's the best way to accomplish this in the HotTowel template. Anyone have already tried and got an answer for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to return a 'viewUrl' property in the view model, so hopefully something like the following will crack the door open ;-).

```
define(function () {
    viewUrl = function () {
        var role = 'role2'; //Hardcoded for demo

        var roleViewMap = {
            'default': 'samples/viewComposition/dFiddle/index.html',
            role1: 'samples/viewComposition/dFiddle/role1.html',
            role2: 'samples/viewComposition/dFiddle/role2.html'
        };

        return roleViewMap[role];

    }

    return {
        viewUrl: viewUrl(),
        propertyOne: 'This is a databound property from the root context.',
        propertyTwo: 'This property demonstrates that binding contexts flow through composed views.'
    };
});
```

Comment: YES! The creators of Durandal have made something awesome! I didn't know the 'viewUrl' is actually used by convention to return the proper view at the display. That's perfect. I am still wondering about the `function strategy(settings):promise`. I am hoping to find more sample about how people have used it, but this is perfect for what I was looking for. Thanks @Rainer.

Comment: Nothing for strategy(settings):promise yet..., but there's a second alternative to static viewUrl property. getView() allows views for a vm change when an ko.observable is updated. Here's a link to a demo: http://spiritag.github.io/dFiddle-1.2-Q-and-A/#/view-composition/getView

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at John Papa's JumpStart course on PluralSight.

Look at the source code from that app here: https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal

In App/Config.js file he adds other routes which are visible by default as :

```
 var routes = [{
        url: 'sessions',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/sessions',
        name: 'Sessions',
        visible: true,
        caption: 'Sessions',
        settings: { caption: '<i class="icon-book"></i> Sessions' }
        }, {
        url: 'speakers',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/speakers',
        name: 'Speakers',
        caption: 'Speakers',
        visible: true,
        settings: { caption: '<i class="icon-user"></i> Speakers' }
        }, {
        url: 'sessiondetail/:id',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/sessiondetail',
        name: 'Edit Session',
        caption: 'Edit Session',
        visible: false
    }, {
        url: 'sessionadd',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/sessionadd',
        name: 'Add Session',
        visible: false,
        caption: 'Add Session',
        settings: { admin: true, caption: '<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Session' }
    }];
```

You can add routes to both the views here using the same logic and then in your productEditor.js you can decide which view to navigate and navigate to that using router.navigateTo() method.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to add two views in the Config.js. There should be an easier way of injecting proper view with a simple function call in Durandal. There is no need to add extra configuration, otherwise if I were to introduce more roles(hence more views), I would have to duplicate the the config entries everytime. Route are not chaning, it's the same, it's just the views that are different based on roles.

Comment: I would personally use css hide and show features to enable disable parts of my HTML page based on user roles. So, if depending on the user roles some part or components the page are visible and other are hidden then I will use knockout bindings to hide or show them. This way I will have to maintain only single view. 

However you want to use same viewmodel and have different views based on user role? Any reason you want to do this way rather than hiding and showing parts of your page?

Comment: yeah, that's true for simple things, like the great project by John Papa. but when you are writing a full blown business application, there are a lot of logics that should not be shared with everybody due to security reason, so just because it's hidden, the content is still available. So I need to have a proper way of injecting restricted edit mode view for roles that are not verified or permitted.

Comment: Can't you use cshtml files instead of normal html? Inside CSHTML you can have if else blocks this way only restricted content will be rendered to the client and your security concerns will be take care of.

Comment: Durandal was designed with mobility in mind, and having the ability to move to PhoneGap with the folder structure, and I like that approach, so I try to stay away from cshtml. Here is a [link](hhttp://bit.ly/ZLVrHj) explaining it more. I know there is an easy and clean way of approaching it, but I haven't cracked that door open yet.